# Where to put `sentry.properties` file in Android Studio project?

Tags: android, sentry

The documentation was not very helpful for me.
Locations I've tried:

- root folder (where `gradle.properties` and project's `build.gradle` files reside)
- `/app` folder (where app's `build.gradle` file is localed)
- `/app/src/main/kotlin`

I initialize Sentry on start of my app in class that extends `android.app.Application` like so:

```
    class MyApp : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Sentry.init(AndroidSentryClientFactory(applicationContext))
    }
}
```

And then do a test capture in one of my methods:

```
Sentry.capture("This is a test capture using Sentry")
```

I also tried to specify the path to `sentry.properties` file explicitly in `gradle.properties` with no luck.

When I use `Sentry.init()` method that accepts DSN, it works, but this is not desired, because I do not want to check DSN into VCS.

I am aware of other methods of configuration, I just want to use `sentry.properties` though.

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: No. I stopped looking for it and moved to LogEntries.

Comment: Unfortunately Sentry has very very bad and confusing installation guide!!!

Comment: I agree the docs are confusing, in fairness though it does currently say 'on Android the default is app/src/main/resources/', see https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/config/#configuration. That works for me, although I'm not sure about having to create such a badly named directory just for sentry's properties file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are in fact **two** different `sentry.properties` files.

1. The `sentry.properties` that is used by the app at runtime to configure the DSN should be placed at `/app/src/main/resources` ([documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/config/#configuration-via-properties-file)).
2. The `sentry.properties` that is used at build time by Gradle to generate and upload ProGuard mappings to Sentry. This should be placed in the project root. ([documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/integrations/#proguard)). This is optional and only relevant for apps that use ProGuard.

Comment: it is wrong way, check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/59070456/4797289

Comment: @RasoulMiri - the answer was correct, but there are now two different sentry.properties files for different purposes. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that the
**`sentry.properties` file should be placed in the root directory of the app.**

For example, if I have setup my project in XYZ folder then put `sentry.properties` in the same folder (it's the same directory where you find AppName.iml, gradle.properties etc etc)

Answer (score 0):

Try it by setting `System Environment Variable` as given here in official documentation:

https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/config/#configuration-via-properties-file

> The Java SDK can be configured via a .properties file that is located on the filesystem or on your application’s classpath. By default the SDK will look for a `sentry.properties` file in the current directory or in the root of your classpath. **You can override the location of the properties file by using either the sentry.properties.file Java System Property or the `SENTRY_PROPERTIES_FILE` System Environment Variable**.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, I know about alternatives, I am just wondering why Sentry cannot find my `sentry.properties` file in the locations, it said it will look for.

Answer (score 0):

In [the documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/config/#id2) it's stated that `app/src/main/resources/` is the default location of sentry.properties for Android.

> By default the SDK will look for a sentry.properties file in the application’s current working directory or in the root of your classpath. (...) on Android the default is `app/src/main/resources/`